# Как просмотреть содержимое поврежденного RAR архива?

Tags: rar

Я недавно скачала rar архив который почему то поврежден. Как я могу просмотреть содержимое не извлекая его? И вообще есть ли способ получить что-нибудь из этого или мне придется скачивать его снова?

Comment: Очень удачливым людям помогает восстановление архива, если архивариус догадался сделать архив с информацией для восстановления. Что значит посмотреть содержимое? Список файлов или сами файлы? Список ещё есть шансы получить, но файлы фиг. С повреждениями разной степени в лучшем случае.

Comment: Вы же хорошо [**погуглили**](https://www.google.ru/#newwindow=1&q=%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%85%D0%B8%D0%B2+rar) прежде чем задать вопрос? Какие действия предпринимали самостоятельно?

Comment: Содержимое файлов любой степени поврежденности смотрится, например, при помощи HIEW, но это наверняка не то, что вам нужно.